# Set android notifications from SQLite DB

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am building a reminder application where the user enters an event into an SQLite DB. The main screen lists the title of each reminder and clicking an item shows the details of it. All of this works fine.

Now I want to allow the user to set up notifications for each item, being given an option to set a reminder for 15 mins, 30 mins, or 1hr before the event is scheduled.

I have no clue how to go about this and can't find any good tutorial on it. Can anyone give me some idea as to how I might implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll use the AlarmManager to set the action to be triggered on the specific date/time. (there're A LOT of tutorials on how to use the AlarmManager)

The alarm manager event always triggers a PendingIntent. From this intent you can either make a broadcast or start a service. (you'll have to create a broadcast receiver or a service)

Then on the broadcast receiver or service you build up and show the notification.

I suggest the broadcast receiver route, it's cleaner and more seamless.
you might also to have a broadcast receiver for onBoot events to re-schedule the events on the alarm manager case the user reboots the device.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [AlaramManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to fire a broadcast that will tell your app to show a notification to the user about the event.

Here is an example of using it: [Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

Answer (score 2):

Once you get the date of the event from the database, it's as easy as any other notification, just keep in mind that you'd subtract the amount of time (the 15,30,60 minutes) to the date.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
Date date = formatter.parse("11/08/2012 16:39");
timer.schedule(timerTask, date);
```

This will schedule the event to the event time, and I'm understanding you want a reminder before the event actually happens. To do this you can create a calendar object to modify the date in the means you need. Remember to remove the previous schedule or you will be left with two reminders (one at the time, and one as a reminder).

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
         cal.setTime(date);
         cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -15);//Or whatever
//Then schedule it.
time.schedule(timerTask,cal.getTime());
```

Both approaches are using the variable `timerTask` which could be something like this, involving the `createNotification` method call that will in fact create the pending notification.

```
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask(){
   @Override
   public void run(){
       createNotification(title,  text,  tickerText,  millisec);
   }
};
```

**There is a potential issue with this thou**. If the application is closed, I believe the timer dies with it, so depending on the nature of your application you may want to use the `AlarmManager` as others have suggested.