# Android code for notifications

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm currently developing an Android application for inventory management using sqlite database. I am storing items information along with the expiry dates. I need help for auto generating notifications when a item expires based on expiry date.

I want to check expiry date of item with current data. If both matches it should give a notification.

Anyone can please help in this coding.
Thank you

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291085/set-android-notifications-from-sqlite-db) will help you.

Comment: Thanks...it was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create BroadcastReceiver to capture alarm manager events and start a notification.
[Here's](http://androidideasblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/alarmmanager-and-notificationmanager.html) a simple example...

Comment: Thanks a lot.. very helpful.